# Change element content XSLT based on element name

Tags: xml, xslt

A XSLT newbie here. I have an XML block that can look like anything, however based on its element name, I need to be able to change its content. The problem is that the XML could be prefixed or not.

A prefixed XML might look like:

```
<POIS xmlns:tns="http://example.com/integration/docs" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <tns:POI>
      <tns:CTL>
         <tns:transaction_date/>
         <tns:record_qualifier/>
         <tns:start_date>2012-10-12 </tns:start_date>
         <tns:test_indicator>P</tns:test_indicator>
       </tns:CTL>
    </tns:POI>
 </tns:POIS>
```

Or not Prefixed:

```
<POIS xmlns="http://example.com/integration/docs"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <POI>
      <CTL>
         <transaction_date/>
         <record_qualifier/>
         <start_date>2012-10-12</start_date>
         <test_indicator>P</test_indicator>
    </CTL>
  </POI>
 </POIS>
```

I want to change the content of the element that ends with **_date** when there is a value.

So a possible output will be:

```
<POIS xmlns:tns="http://example.com/integration/docs" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <tns:POI>
      <tns:CTL>
         <tns:transaction_date/>
         <tns:record_qualifier/>
         <tns:start_date>20121012 </tns:start_date>
         <tns:test_indicator>P</tns:test_indicator>
    </tns:CTL>
   </tns:POI> 
 </tns:POIS>
```

This is what I have so far:

The problem is that it complains with **tns: namespace** on the changed element when prefixed or put a blank namespace for non-prefixed XML element.

Any solutions? This is a utility transformation so I would like to keep it as generic as possible.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"      
    xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/
    java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()[ends-with(name(), '_date')]">
     <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="(text())" >
             <xsl:element name="{name()}" >
      <xsl:value-of select ="xp20:format-dateTime(text(),'[Y0001][M01][D01]')" /> 
      </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>   
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>  
       </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed: `<CTL>` should end with `</CTL>`, missing `</POI>` closing tag, inconsistent prefixing on `<POIS>` tag.  Please fix your XML.

Comment: Try changing `<xsl:element name="{name()}">` to `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">`...does that help?

Comment: Unfortunately, It still fails, since it is putting a blank namespace  '<start_date xmlns="">20120430</start_date>' .

Comment: Also, I dont even need to add the element if there was any other way to just change the value inside.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue:     <xsl:template match="node()[ends-with(name(), '_date')]//text()">
 <xsl:value-of select="xp20:format-dateTime(.,'[Y0001][M01][D01]')"/>
 </xsl:template>
 
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `<xsl:element name="{name()}">` to `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">`.